# Environments with default font, another texts as \textsf

Tags: fonts, environments

I'd like to set the font of a document as the one produced by `\textsf{}`, but keep the default font in environments like definitions and theorems. My attempt as to declare

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheoremstyle{defi}% name
{3pt}% Space above
{3pt}% Space below
{crm}% Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\itshape}% Theorem head font
{:}% Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}% Space after theorem head
{}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)

\begin{document}

\begin{defi} Text with default font. \end{defi}

Text in sans-serif font.

\end{document}
```

But it doesn't work, since the font is defined as sans-serif over all the text. I'm wondering if the body font I stated above is right. If someone could give a hint, I'd be grateful. I was advised not to use this sans-serif font to typeset my document. So, I'd like some suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please provide a complete minimal working example (MWE), that starts at `\documentclass`, includes all necessary packages and ends at `\end{document}`? This helps the people to help you.

Comment: Welcome! Without an MWE, there isn't actually much point in trying to answer this. What does 'environments like definitions and theorems' mean? Can you give a complete list of the environments you want to use serif in? Incidentally, it is poor typography to use sans for your main body text unless you are typesetting something like a presentation, poster, pamphlet etc.

Comment: `\rmfamily\itshape`

Comment: Please do not use sans serif font to typeset your entire document. Sans serif fonts are for display, e.g. headers and the specific applications mentioned by @cfr . Your document will become utterly unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least a couple of issues:

- the font should be specified as `\rmfamily`, not as `cmr`;
- you must invoke your new style before the `\newtheorem` statement.

Try this:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\newtheoremstyle{defi}% name
    {3pt}% Space above
    {3pt}% Space below
    {\rmfamily}% Body font
    {}% Indent amount
    {\rmfamily\itshape}% Theorem head font
    {:}% Punctuation after theorem head
    {.5em}% Space after theorem head
    {}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning "normal")

\theoremstyle{defi}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}[section] % not "chapter" because I'm using the 
                                       % "article" document class



\begin{document}

\section{A title}

Some text before the first definition: this text should be in ``sans-serif''.

\begin{defi}
    This is a definition, and it should be in \verb|\rmfamily| (that is, 
    \emph{with} serifs).
\end{defi}

Some text after the definition, again in \verb|\sffamily|.

\end{document}
```

You can check by yourself that the result is just poor typography:

[image: Output of the code]

Indeed, to typeset an article (or, worse, a report: you were using chapters, weren’t you?) in a sans-serif fonts is already questionable by itself; but to set, *within* such a document, the definitions with serifs…